# Size of the Response pane in Postman Rest Client UI

Tags: postman

In the UI for the Postman REST Client for Chrome, is there a way to configure the size of the Response pane? It's too large and not contained within the Postman window. I can't simply grab it with the mouse and resize it, as I can with the Request pane.

[The pane drops below the viewable part of the window.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xxgia.png)

Answer (score 1):

**No, in fact, you cannot change its size.**

But what stops you from scrolling your main window to the bottom? Do it and then you'll be able to scroll your preview.

[image]

Comment: Nothing, of course. I was just looking for an alternative answer.